# How to add an InstanceSpecification to a Package using org.eclipse.uml2 API

Tags: java, tool-uml

Here is a simple task for you who know the `org.eclispe.uml2` API:

I'd like to add an `org.eclipse.uml2.uml.InstanceSpecification` to an `org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Package`, but how is that done?

```
Package package = model.createNestedPackage("MyInstancePackage");       
InstanceSpecification is = UMLFactory.eINSTANCE.createInstanceSpecification();
// package.someMethod(is) <--- ???
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This was really easy as expected:

```
package.getPackagedElements().add(is);
```